# class file for android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayoutImpl not found on travis support-v4 21.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric, travis-ci, android-espresso

We are trying to run tests on travis CI. We have a class which uses `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`.

When we use android support v4 library 

`build.gradle`->

```
targetSdkVersion: 19
`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'`
```

`.travis.yml`

```
- build-tools-19.1.0
- android-19
- extra-android-support
- extra-google-google_play_services
- extra-google-m2repository
```

we donot get this error but on using

`build.gradle` ->

```
targetSdkVersion: 21
com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+
```

`.travis.yml`

```
- build-tools-21.0.1
- android-21
- extra-android-support
- extra-google-google_play_services
- extra-google-m2repository
```

We get the error

```
 private static class IdlingDrawerListener implements DrawerListener, IdlingResource {
                   ^
  class file for android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayoutImpl not found
/home/travis/build/something/sample/src/test/java/com/abc/somesample/espresso/DrawerActions.java:200: error: cannot find symbol
        private ResourceCallback callback;
                ^
  symbol:   class ResourceCallback
  location: class IdlingDrawerListener
/home/travis/build/something/sample/src/test/java/com/abc/somesample/espresso/DrawerActions.java:255: error: cannot find symbol
        public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback callback) {
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class ResourceCallback
  location: class IdlingDrawerListener
/home/travis/build/something/sample/src/test/java/com/abc/somesample/espresso/DrawerActions.java:153: error: method setDrawerListener in class DrawerLayout cannot be applied to given types;
                drawer.setDrawerListener(IdlingDrawerListener.getInstance(existingListener));
                      ^
  required: DrawerListener
  found: IdlingDrawerListener
  reason: actual argument IdlingDrawerListener cannot be converted to DrawerListener by method invocation conversion
/home/travis/build/something/sample/src/test/java/com/abc/somesample/espresso/DrawerActions.java:192: error: cannot find symbol
                instance = new IdlingDrawerListener();
                           ^
  symbol:   constructor IdlingDrawerListener()
  location: class IdlingDrawerListener
/home/travis/build/something/sample/src/test/java/com/abc/somesample/espresso/DrawerActions.java:193: error: method registerIdlingResources in class Espresso cannot be applied to given types;
                Espresso.registerIdlingResources(instance);
                        ^
  required: IdlingResource[]
  found: IdlingDrawerListener
  reason: argument type IdlingDrawerListener does not conform to vararg element type IdlingResource
/home/travis/build/something/sample/src/test/java/com/abc/somesample/espresso/DrawerActions.java:205: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
            this.parentListener = parentListener;
            ^
/home/travis/build/something/sample/src/test/java/com/abc/somesample/espresso/DrawerActions.java:205: error: cannot find symbol
            this.parentListener = parentListener;
                ^
  symbol: variable parentListener
/home/travis/build/something/sample/src/test/java/com/abc/somesample/espresso/DrawerActions.java:208: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
/home/travis/build/something/sample/src/test/java/com/abc/somesample/espresso/DrawerActions.java:215: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^

/home/travis/build/something/sample/src/test/java/com/abc/somesample/espresso/DrawerActions.java:256: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
            this.callback = callback;
            ^
/home/travis/build/something/sample/src/test/java/com/abc/somesample/espresso/DrawerActions.java:256: error: cannot find symbol
            this.callback = callback;
                ^
  symbol: variable callback
/home/travis/build/something/sample/src/test/java/com/abc/somesample/espresso/DrawerActions.java:254: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
```

Travis even shows that it has downloaded and installed Android Support Library revision 21, but still the above error.

**Update:**

We tried to run tests on the VM set up by travis guys.

- The tests failed with the same error when ran on the machine initially.
- Tried by manually copying `internal_impl-21.0.0.jar` found inside the `support-v4` `aar` file to our `libs/` directory and the tests passed.
- Manually installed `Android SDK tools 23.0.5` on the VM and the tests passed.

Our project `.travis.yml` has the following lines:

`- tools
 - platform-tools
 - build-tools-21.1.1
 - android-21
 - extra-android-support
 - extra-android-m2repository
 - extra-google-m2repository`

Still the tests are failing on travis.

Comment: How is this being built? v20 of the support library doesn't have a DrawerLayoutImpl at all; v21 has it, but it's not in classes.jar in the archive; it's in libs/internal_impl-20.0.0.jar. However, a test case builds okay for me, so I'm not sure what's different about your setup. Does Gradle build it okay from the command line on your workstation?

Comment: A similar bug is reported in the AOSP issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=77682

Comment: @ScottBarta yes. gradle is building it okay from the command line on my workstation. On my workstation inside support library v21: I can see `DrawerLayoutImpl` inside the classes.jar.

Comment: I've got the same problem on Jenkins build system. It works fine on local machine, but crashes on Jenkins for some reason.

Comment: @Mikooos You can easily check the androidsdk in your machine running jenkins. Is there any difference in the classes in v21 jar in your local machine and v21 jar in the jenkins machine

Comment: I had the same issue with Jenkins. After much experimentation I was able to find a fix for my project. The problem stems from building a freshly cloned project. The first build will fail, and subsequent builds will succeed. You can try this on your local machine to verify. The solution for Jenkins was to delete the step which cleared the workspace, however I can't think of a solution for Travis.

Comment: So right now the only fix is to manually install or manually include the jar mentioned above? Is that what you're doing for the time being?

Comment: yes! that's what we are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited Answer:

This issue is fixed by using the pre-compiled `DrawerActions.java` class from the `espresso-contrib` library. For setup instructions see the [link](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions).

Comment: Still getting this error using gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Comment: @dnkoutso see the edited answer. Have you copied `DrawerActions.java` or you are using the `espresso-contrib` library?

Comment: @ragdroid which one are you supposed to use?

Comment: use the `espresso-contrib` library.

Comment: @ragdroid Could you elaborate on your answer, possibly provide an example? Merely adding `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'` to my build.gradle does not fix the issue...

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in travis. If it does not use Gradle to build everything but does some building on its own (which it sounds like, given that you have special YAML files listing dependencies), it needs to handle AAR file dependencies by not just including classes.jar, but jars under libs/ as well.

Comment: What is it that Travis needs to do? Travis runs `gradle build connectedCheck` (http://git.io/4Th6Xg) when an appropriate file is found. What else is required?

Comment: @tor-norbye issue was raised regarding this: [issue link](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2897)

Answer (score 1):

**1. ActionBarDrawerToggle: deprecation, new version style for Lollipop and updated samples**

[DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) has a nested interface [DrawerListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html) implemented by:

1. [android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle (deprecated on API 21)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html).
2. [android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle (recommended  version)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html).

The new [support-v7-appcompat](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) version is compatible with [Android Lollipop](https://www.android.com/versions/lollipop-5-0/) and [Material Design](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) style.

See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27086157/1009132) to update it, or the [Google I/O app implementation](https://github.com/google/iosched) and [Google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NavigationDrawer).

Requires latest SDK version, appcompat-v7.21.0.+, support-v4.21.0.+ and Android Support Repository.

---

**2. Travis configuration: Latest SDK tools, platform-tools, build-tools and extra-m2repository required**

Add `extra-android-m2repository` and  `build-tools-21.1.1` to `android: components:`.

[Travis CI for Android projects](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/#CI-Environment-for-Android-Projects) uses tools 23.0.2 by default, Lollipop requires [SDK tools 23.0.5](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/platforms.html#5.0).

> Important: To download the most recent Android system components from
>   the Android SDK Manager, you must first update the SDK Tools to the
>   most recent release and restart the SDK Manager. If you do not, the
>   latest Android system components will not be available for download.

You need update SDK `tools` first so you get the latest revisions of the other components. Tools v23.0.5 requires `platform-tools` v19+ to be updated and v21+ to work. Plus platform, sys-img, etc. Try this:

```
android:
  components:
    # Uncomment the lines below if you want to
    # use the latest revision of Android SDK Tools
    - platform-tools
    - tools
    - build-tools-21.1.1
    - android-21
    - extra-android-support
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-21
  licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-license-5be876d5'
```

---

**3. Important: Gradle based projects require extra-android-m2repository no extra-android-support**

`extra-android-m2repository` contains the artifacts (.aar files) for gradle/android studio.

> Note: If you're developing with Android Studio, select and install
>   the Android Support Repository item instead (of Android Support
>   Library on Eclipse).

Further info for Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

---

**4. The missing DrawerLayoutImpl class contained in android.support:support-v4:21.0.2 internal .jar**

[image: Missing DrawerLayoutImpl]

You can try to change `21.0.+` to `21.0.2`. I'm not sure about Travis-ci dependency resolution workflow.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
```

I dont know but perhaps it copies other android.support version  without the inner missing class and jar.

Check if the internal jar is there by adding something as this to your build:

```
export MOD_NAME= yourapplicationmodulename

'cat ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/${MOD_NAME}/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/libraryList.txt'
```

If you use 21.0.+ and download the m2repository 21.0.0 version but then looks for updated versions on maven it foundd Android Support Library, revision 21.0.1 without the aar, so try the new 21.0.2 version.

---

**5. Espresso or Double Espresso, DrawerActions, espresso-contrib jar and other dependencies**

About `Espresso` and other transitive dependencies to old support libraries, you could try to upgrade them or exclude the android.support [dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton.espresso/espresso-support-v4/1.1-r2):

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

I'm not familiar with `Double espresso`, a pure Gradle port of the Espresso testing utility for Android but Jake Wharton writes [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso/) ([Related issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65445)):

> Duplicated Dependencies
>
> Due to a bug in the current Android plugin, you may need to exclude
>   dependencies which are duplicated in both the app and test app.
>
> For example, if you have a dependency on Dagger you will need to
>   manually exclude it from the test dependency for the time being.
>
> androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3') {
>   exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger' } The following are the
>   dependencies of Espresso which may need to be temporarily excluded:
>
> com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1 ... and those of the 'support-v4'
>   module:
>
> com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0 <-----------

About [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso), I read that supports up to kitkat but I don't know if Lollipop is now  fully supported and I found a related issue about [Espresso.registerIdlingResources(instance)](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=65&thanks=65&ts=1396432619) and I quote from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso#To_use_Espresso_without_dependencies):

> Sometimes you want to use a version of Espresso where you are in
>   control of the dependencies For example, Espresso utilizes Hamcrest
>   Matchers and therefore has an explicit dependency on it. To avoid
>   errors while Dexing your test code **you can use the no dependencies
>   version of Espresso and explicitly declare your dependencies**
>
> If you need any functionality from the contrib library, such as
>   **DrawerActions**, copy the **espresso-contrib jar** from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/#git%2Fbin%2Fespresso-contrib-dependencies).
>   Espresso actions for using a **DrawerLayout**.

---

**6. ProGuard shrinking step: update rules for API 21 changes**

I'm using [Google I/O app implementation](https://github.com/google/iosched) as I saw you are doing to learn Material Design and all this stuff. They recently [updated the app, added app-compat and fixed nav drawer](https://github.com/ardock/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java#L375) but I think they didn't update ProGuard rules. If you are using a similar configuration, I suggest you update it and check the aapt rules to be sure missing classes are kept.

As an experimental sample, I'm learning it too, I added the [new API 21 View constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int,%20int)) and `includedescriptorclasses`

```
# Added includedescriptorclasses for unkept android.support descriptors
-keep,includedescriptorclasses public class * extends android.view.View {
public <init>(android.content.Context);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int); # Added in API 21
public void set*(...);
```

And 43 of 44 notes about unkept descriptors were solved, included

> Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout { void setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener'

Comment: I added another possibility. Perhaps you need v7 appcompat. Plus extra-android-m2repository...

Comment: I did a rollback, the solution was in bold in the last line of point 5 but you said that it was a gradle issue http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27358362/revisions and I deleted it when they updated espresso :)

Answer (score 1):

Manually adding the library to the server in build.gradle worked:

```
testCompile fileTree(dir: "${rootDir}/YourProject/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/", include: "**/*.jar")
```

Comment: This worked for me with Shippable. This is weird and I'm not sure what is going on but it works...

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into this issue(?) https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77682#c11.

The last comment, by @Tor Norbye, ironically :), says

> The class loader issue is fixed for 0.8.14. The gradle sync issue has
>   to be fixed on the model side in Gradle 0.14.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple tests, it worked for me adding the dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:internal_impl:22.2.0'
```

Unfortunately, you have to keep this JAR updated, when you change the 'support' lib version.