# Migrating from SimonVT MenuDrawer to DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, drawerlayout

Seen as now the DrawerLayout is included in the support libraries, I have been looking for a tutorial or guide for migrating from SimonVT MenuDrawer to the official DrawerLayout.

I have only found questions like this:
[Navigation drawer (menudrawer) Android 5 (lollipop) style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433306/navigation-drawer-menudrawer-android-5-lollipop-style)

The problem I see is that implementing DrawerLayout implies changing/reorganizing ALL of my layouts xml.

I'd like some guidance about the best way to proceed.

Thanks

References:

[SimonVT/android-menudrawer](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer)

[Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: Why does implementing DrawLayout imply changing all of your XML?

Comment: The way I implemented menudrawer , I just programmatically include my pure layouts as part of the content of a MenuDrawer object. Can I do the same thing with Drawerlayout?

Comment: Typically with a DrawerLayout you would specify a single layout with a Drawer. When you switch content, you just swap out a part of the layout with a new Fragment, so yes, you would have to update all of your layouts.

Comment: I see. I'll begin to work on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unfortunate truth is that you'll have to update all of your layout files.

The typical (recommended) setup for the navigation drawer is to define a single layout file and swap out the content (current content fragment) with another one.