# Android do ToolBar icon animation programmatically

Tags: android, animation, material-design

[image: animation]

How can I run animation of opening drawer at moment I want? 
I used SupportLibrary v7 use "hamburger" animation.
Want to write method like this:

```
class Activity extends ActionBarActivity{
   ToolBar toolbar;
   ActionBarDrawerToggle toogle;

   ...

   private void setToolBarIconState(State state) {
      if (state == State.menu) {
          //flipIconToMenu ?
      } else {
          //flipIconToBackPointer ?
      }
   }
```

Comment: Do you want to override the default behavior? Or is this separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve it you need to use canvas.

if you want tutorial then please follwo below link:

https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer

https://github.com/balysv/material-menu

https://github.com/ikimuhendis/LDrawer

https://github.com/HeinrichReimer/material-drawer

https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template

https://github.com/Zlate87/material-navigation-drawer-example

https://github.com/Zlate87/material-navigation-drawer-example

Answer (score 1):

I think that is the default animation from v7 appcompat library

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430974/drawer-indicator-in-lollipop-play-store) out.

Comment: Yes, I've already done it. I want write method to change state not depends on opened drawer, but depends on other actions,

Comment: Well taking a peek in v7 source code it looks like they extend DrawerArrowDrawable class

Comment: You can use this library in your app https://github.com/ChrisRenke/DrawerArrowDrawable